# DotNetNuke custom action on user registration

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I need to perform a custom action when new user is registered on DotNetNuke 7 website. Namely, I need to determine user's country from IP and change user access level based on country. I know how to get country from IP, but modifying registration process is problem for me (I'm almost completely new in DNN). Is there any easy way to modify registration process, or make code to run when user registered, without creating a separate module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the core of DNN, but i wouldn't recommend it. I would look at a module like Dynamic Registration from DataSprings http://www.datasprings.com

That allows you quite a bit of customization of the registration process as I recall, DNN itself doesn't provide anything like you are looking for out of the box.